# How do I open a directory and open each file in the directory?

Tags: php, file, directory

I am trying to open a directory and open each file in the directory.

This is the code I have for opening my directory;

```
$handle = opendir ('hoe7b_data');
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
echo "$file<br />";
}
closedir($handle);
```

I now want my code to open each file one by one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $fileHandle = fopen($entry, "r");
            while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
                $fileContent = fgets($fileHandle);
                echo $fileContent;
            }
            fclose($fileHandle);
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`is_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) to check if it is a file and [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the contents as a string.

```
$handle = opendir ('hoe7b_data');
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
  if (is_file($file)) {
    $file_content = file_get_contents($file);
    echo $file_content;
  }
}
closedir($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Am sure you don't want to just output anything  ....

```
$type = array("txt");
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ( $fi as $file ) {
    if (in_array($file->getExtension(), $type))
        echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```